# Interact with Lottie animation elements

Tags: android, lottie

Using the [Lottie Android](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android) library, is it possibly to let the user interact with elements of the animation that is being played?

Like, have a button in the animation (not a native button) and react to clicks on it?

Comment: No user can not interact with animation because its mostly created in Adobe after effect and then converted in json using plugins. Its very difficult to edit `json` file because its affect whole animation.

Answer (score 1):

The json file is interpreted and outputs SVGs to the DOM. These can be assigned an eventhandler like any other element.

From Bodymovin:

> name your layers in starting with a "." or a "#" and they will get exported with the name as a class or an id respectively.